# How to debug Web Essentials TypeScript Bundle?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome-devtools, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

I have *file1.ts* and *file2.ts*. I added them to the [Web Essentials Bundle](http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling) *all.js.bundle*:

```
<bundle ...>
  ...
  <files>
    <file>/public/file1.ts</file>
    <file>/public/file2.ts</file>
  </files>
</bundle>
```

Generated *all.min.js.map* file reflects *all.min.js* on compiled TypeScript files: *file1.js* and *file2.js*. Compiled TypeScript files have js.map files too: *file1.js.map* and *file2.js.map*.

But automatically browsers use *all.min.js.map* only and don't use child js.map files (*file1.js.map* and *file2.js.map*). How to fix it? I tested it in Chrome and IE10, is there a problem in other browsers?